# Pegar determinado número de uma string no select

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Preciso pegar um determinado número que está dentro de uma string (no caso o retorno de um `select`). Na tabela está gravado assim:

```
CreditCash_Aderencia_AD_20180823;20180823;Arquivo convertido para CSV com 503 linhas
CreditCash_Aderencia_20180823;20180823;Arquivo convertido para CSV com 1399 linhas
CreditCash_Aderencia;20180823;Não foi possível executar o sistema em 3 tentativas
CreditCash_Aderencia_AD_20180822;20180822;Arquivo convertido para CSV com 500 linhas
```

Nessa string eu preciso pegar somente o número que está antes de `linhas`, no caso o 503 por exemplo (que pode ser variável).

Preciso desse número pois irei colocar em um `update` para fazer alterações somente nos que tiverem mais que 500 linhas convertidas.

Comment: Eu jurei que tinha PHP aí, kkkkkkk. Minha resposta ficou errada

Comment: qual banco de dados vc está usando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código abaixo permite-lhe atingir o que pretende:

```
DECLARE @strText    NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @intAlpha   INT

SET @strText = 'CreditCash_Aderencia_AD_20180823;20180823;Arquivo convertido para CSV com 503 linhas'
SET @strText = RIGHT(@strText, CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(@strText) + ';') - 1)

SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText)

BEGIN
    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText    = STUFF(@strText, @intAlpha, 1, '')
        SET @intAlpha   = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText)
    END
END

SELECT ISNULL(@strText, 0)
```

Pode sempre adaptar isso para um função para usar em consultas:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetOnlyNumber (@Text NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intAlpha   INT

    SET @Text = RIGHT(@Text, CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(@Text) + ';') - 1)

    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @Text)

    BEGIN
        WHILE @intAlpha > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Text       = STUFF(@Text, @intAlpha, 1, '')
            SET @intAlpha   = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @Text)
        END
    END

    RETURN ISNULL(@Text, 0)
END
```

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno, mas dessa maneira que você fez ele trouxe os números do começo também. Então eu dei um substring e deu certo, porque peguei o final da string. Obrigado pela dica da função !